# Create pipe from one file to another in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe

In my school we have to program in C this assignment:

PART2:   Write three programs A, B, C.

A will start B and C using `fork()` and `exec()` system calls.

While starting it will redirect the both output and input of both B and C
to a pipe.

B will be receiving number from its standard input and incrementing it
by 5, printing the result on its standard output.

C will be receiving a number from its standard input and diving it by 2,
printing the result on its standard output.

The role of A will be to seed this computation with a random number to B,
then retrieve result from B, send it to C, take result from C, send it to B, etc. until this repeats for 100 times.

It is nice if A will wait 1 second between sending the data to the other process.

A will be printing on its own standard output all data passing from
processes to other, for instance:

`001. A -> B 10` 
`B -> A 15`
`A -> C 15`
`C -> A 7`
`002. A -> B 7`
`B -> A 12...`

I already have files B and C. However I have no idea how to program file A which controls everything. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please ask a more specific question than "help me". For example is it `fork` you have trouble with? Is it the piping? Is it `exec`? Something else? Please show as much of the code as you can do and ask a specific question about the one step you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Each process holds a file-descriptor table, when you fork(), the child process inherits a copy of the table from the parent process.
So if you have a pipe in process A, so when you fork - the child process will also have the pipe's file descriptor in its table.
Another requirement is that B and C will receive through the standard input,
which is FD 0.
you can override between the standard input's FD and the pipe's FD using dup2 function.
this way FD 0 will now be directed to the pipe, and when you fork to process B, its standard input will now be from the pipe. You can do the same for the standard output FD (1).
I suggest keeping a copy of the original standard I/O FD using dup() so you could recover them back for process A once you finished forking.

Comment: Is there some way you could show me example of the code please? Because I still am not able to understand the concept.